# Prblem with equal heights jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a div with id=group1port.
Inside this div are multiple divs, one being id group1porteq.
I am using the equal heights to make the div's the same height however, with what I have, it currently changes the heights of all the div's, when I only want it to effect the div group1porteq. I have tried ('#group1port div.group1porteq') but this doesn't work. I have also tried removing the "div" completely and that also doesn't work. Also have tried changing it to ('#group1porteq div') and then that just makes all the div's inside that div equal.

The "div class="portlet light bordered" id="group1porteq"" is the two div's i need to have equal height

I have div's that all have multiple div's inside, and I am trying to just get equal height for 1 div. Here is a sample of the script.

```
     <script>
     if($(window).width() > 800){
         $('#group1port div').equalHeights();
     }
    </script>
```

Here is a sample of the code

```
<div class="row" id="group1port">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="portlet light bordered" id="group1porteq">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart font-dark hide"></i>
                    <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase">Bulletin</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="portlet light bordered" id="group1porteq">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <i class="icon-bar-chart font-dark hide"></i>
                    <span class="caption-subject font-dark bold uppercase">Bulletin</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="portlet-body">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you included a reference to the equalHeights plugin?
https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what div's you're trying to find, but this find's both 'group1porteq' divs nested within the 'group1port' div.

```
$('#group1port').find('#group1porteq').each(function() {
    // Do equal height stuff
});
```

I don't know what equalHeights(), but it sounds like your issues are all related to the selectors.  You can find a full list of selector options here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate id: id="group1porteq" on two divs. You cannot have an id be the same on a page. Try changing it to a class as a first step. Can you add some CSS to this bit of code? it would seem that you are trying to break a table apart. Try adding "display: block" to the class: class="group1porteq" once you change that and see if it breaks the table model so you can get individual heights again.